# Good extension name for a war file with source

Tags: java, web-applications, naming, file-extension

Is there a name for a Java Webapp's war that includes the source code? We will be using a webserver that accepts Java Web Projects with source code) uploaded into the docroot folder, so `docroot/admin.webapp.zip` would be the place to upload a webapp that handles `http://example.com/admin`. This way the compiled binaries and source code are together (and down the road, even the compiled code might not be there at all, but compiled on the first runtime).

What are the most common file types for a webapp with source? If it means lining up with a standard, I would be glad to use a similar extension name and zip directory structure. If not, I will probably use something like `.web.zip`. I would just use `.zip`, but then the webserver would not know if it should serve out the zip or only use it as a webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the Maven standard can help.

For JAR files containing source the naming convention is example-1.0.0-sources.jar. Equally a WAR file could follow as example-1.0.0-sources.war.

I imagine the source itself would be in WEB-INF/src.

You then deploy as normal since the artifact is already zipped.